# Why this simple kusto script is not working?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

The below print statement always returns empty string. Why is it happening?

```
let tspanString=strcat(tostring(toint(rand(100))),'d');
print totimespan(tspanString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result of `strcat(N, 'd')` is a non constant string in a format that can't be parsed into a timespan literal, when passed into `totimespan()`.

A valid alternative in your case would be using `rand(100) * 1d`

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic

Comment: Then why this is working? let tspanString=tostring('23d');
print totimespan(tspanString)

Comment: `23d` is a contasnt string literal, whereas `strcat(N, 'd')` is not